# Почему в консоли браузера появляются ошибки ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT?

Tags: веб-программирование

Почему появляются эти ошибки в консоли браузера?

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT ad_status.js

Comment: Потому что AdBlock

Comment: @Cristian он реагирует на ключевые "слова". Если вы назовете класс вроде ad - ловите ошибку.